# Adiabatic Relation in Plasma Invariant and Thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

[image]

In the problem above, I know how to do the 1D part. Basically, you just plug $V_{\parallel} = 
\frac{J}{L}$ into $\langle \frac{1}{2} m v^2\rangle = \frac{1}{2} k T$. After you get $T$ in terms of $L$, you plug $T$ into ideal gas law. The result $PV^3 =$ Constant agrees with the adiabatic relation in the thermodynamics.

But I don't know how to approach the 3D case. Obviously, the answer should be $PV^{5/3} =$ Constant, which agrees with the thermodynamic relation. I know the kinetic energy will change to $\frac{3}{2} kT$. Is the adiabatic invariant $J$ going to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thank you for this illustrative question.  The 3D case pretty much follows the same line of reasoning.  For each dimension, we have an adiabatic invariant, and rougly
\begin{align}
J &= \oint p \, dq \\
&= 2 \int_0^L p \, dq = 2 \, m \, v_\parallel L, \tag{1}
\end{align}
here we can interpret $v_\parallel$ as any of $|v_x|$, $|v_y|$ and $|v_z|$.  Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} m v_\parallel^2 = \frac{1}{2} C \, k T,
\tag{2}
\end{align}
where $C$ is a dimensionless constant around $1.0$.
Using Eq. (1) in Eq. (2) we get
\begin{align}
m \frac{J^2}{4 \, m^2 L^2} = C \, k T.
\tag{3}
\end{align}

Now in $D$ dimensions,
we have $V = L^D$.
Further, the ideal gas law gives
$$
P V = n k T.
\tag{4}
$$
If we use $V^{1/D}$ for $L$, and replace $kT$ by $PV/n$ in Eq. (3), we get
$$
\frac{J^2}{4 \, m V^\frac{2}{D}}
=
\frac{C}{n} PV,
$$
or
$$
PV^{\frac{D+2}{D}} = \frac{J^2 \, n}{4 \, C \, m} = \mathrm{constant}.
$$